# xquery not finding attribute in xpath search

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following xml code, similarly structured across multiple files:

```
<surface n="verso">
    <label>Folio 42 Verso</label>
        <graphic url="British_Library_Harley_2251_f42v.jpg"/>
            <zone n="EETS.QD.I">
                <line n="l.1">
                    <orig><hi rend="red_pilcrow">¶</hi><hi rend="underline">Quis dabit capite meo fonte<ex>m </ex>lacrima<ex>rum</ex></hi></orig>
                </line>
            </zone>
    </label>
</surface>
```

I need to generate a link to an .html file that is named the same as the image above.  My code to do so in XQuery is as follows:

```
let $g := concat($t, "/" , $m, "/", substring-before($l/../../tei:graphic/@url,"."),".html")
```

$l indicates an individual line, so the location of the <line> element above. The value of $t and $m are generated in another let statement, and in this case equal "Quis_Dabit" and "British_Library_Harley_2251," respectively.  So $g should equal "Quis_Dabit/British_Library_Harley_2251/British_Library_Harley_2251_f42v.html" but instead I just get the .html at the end: "Quis_Dabit/British_Library_Harley_2251/.html."  The flaw seems to be in my substring-before statement, but it does not display anything about tei:graphic (name(), @url, etc) and does display the @n element for surface if I include that instead of tei:graphic.  So I'm at a bit of a loss.  How do I form the substring-before correctly, and can someone explain to me where the logic is screwing up so I don't run into this error again?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression:

> ```
> let $g := concat($t, "/" , $m, "/", substring-before($l/../../tei:graphic/@url,"."),".html")
> ```

This is, as written, not a complete or valid XQuery or XPath expression, but let's assume it is part of a larger statement.

Let's simplify that a bit:

```
let $g := substring-before($l/../../tei:graphic/@url,".")
```

Let's now assume that your variable `$l` is correctly set to the node you are saying it is

```
let $g := substring-before(//line[@n="l.1"]/../../tei:graphic/@url,".")
```

And let's assume that the element `graphic` in your input XML is indeed in the namespace bound by `tei` (removed in the online test below for simplicity).

Now, let's fix your XML (it is not well-formed). If the self-closing tags are correct, this is a possible version of your XML:

```
<surface n="verso">
    <label>Folio 42 Verso</label>
        <graphic url="British_Library_Harley_2251_f42v.jpg"/>
            <zone n="EETS.QD.I">
                <line n="l.1">
                    <orig><hi rend="red_pilcrow">¶</hi><hi rend="underline">Quis dabit capite meo fonte<ex>m </ex>lacrima<ex>rum</ex></hi></orig>
                </line>
            </zone>
</surface>
```

This is a very misleading way of indenting the XML (you got me fooled!), I prefer parent/child indentation like this, much clearer:

```
<surface n="verso">
    <label>Folio 42 Verso</label>
    <graphic url="British_Library_Harley_2251_f42v.jpg" />
    <zone n="EETS.QD.I">
        <line n="l.1">
            <orig>
                <hi rend="red_pilcrow">¶</hi>
                <hi rend="underline">Quis dabit capite meo fonte<ex>m </ex>lacrima<ex>rum</ex></hi>
            </orig>
        </line>
    </zone>
</surface>
```

This expression can be [tested with your input automatically here, at XPathTester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/d73707cd2e628a0819eb89a85f809d8c).

As you can see it returns the correct string. There is nothing wrong with your XPath or XQuery skills :).

So your error is either in not having the focus on the `line` element, the `graphic` element is not in the said namespace, or something else you didn't show is wrong.